# Setting Environment Variables in SQL Agent Job for SSIS using PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, ssis

I was trying to simplify the scheduling SQL Agent Job for SSIS and I came across [this](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.in/2016/10/using-powershell-to-create-sql-agent.html) wonderful article. Now I need to assign Environment variables for the scheduled SSIS package using this script.

Passing `ENVREFERENCE [identifier]` attribute in command can solve this, but I want to pass the `[identifier]` dynamically.

Can anyone suggest the best way to do so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What code have you got so far?

Comment: You can refer the link in the post, i.e. http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.in/2016/10/using-powershell-to-create-sql-agent.html. I have tried this and made small changes as needed.